# The Limit of a Matrix Series

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-analysis

I have an invertible matrix $B$ and a diagonal (not necessarily invertible) matrix $D$ and I'm studying the series as $n\to\infty$ of $\frac{1}{n} B \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}( I - \frac{1}{n} B^T D B)^k B^T D$. I expect that the series should converge to $B(B^T D B)^\dagger B^T D$, where $\dagger$ denotes the matrix pseudoinverse.

Here is a hand wavy argument. As $n$ grows, the sum approaches the geometric series and the expression becomes $\frac{1}{n} B \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}( I - \frac{1}{n} B^T D B)^k B^T D$. We can now use the equality $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} C^k = (I - C)^{-1}$ to conclude that $\frac{1}{n} B \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}( I - \frac{1}{n} B^T D B)^k B^T D = \frac{1}{n} B (I - ( I - \frac{1}{n} B^T D B))^{-1} B^T D = \frac{1}{n}  B( \frac{1}{n} B^T D B)^{-1} B^T D =  B (B^T D B)^{-1} B^T D$.

Of course, this assumes that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (I - \frac{1}{n} B^T D B)^k$ converges, which it doesn't for large enough $n$. How can I develop a fully rigorous analytical argument?

Comment: If you calculate this limit for scalars you get an exponential and your conjectured limit does not seem to hold.

Comment: I looked at the limit for scalars but I couldn't solve it either. I can unroll the $(1- 1/n bdb)^k$ term into a binomial expansion but I don't know how I would turn that expression into an exponential.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-(b/n))^k = \frac{1}{b}[1-(1-(b/n))^n]$ by summing the geometric progression. Now if you write this expression as $\frac{1}{b}[1-e^{n\log(1-(b/n))}]$ it is easy to see it has the limit $(1-e^{-b})/b$.

Comment: If $B$ is a symmetric invertible matrix you can use diagonalization to do roughly the same calculation and get $\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(I-n^{-1}B)^k=B^{-1}(1-e^{-B})$.